# how to superimpose two images?

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I have a visualization output of gabor filter with 12 different orientations.I want to superimpose the vizualization image on my image of retina for vessel extraction.How do i do it?I have tried the below method.is there any other method to perform superimposition of images in matlab.

here is my code

```
         I = getimage();
         I=I(:,:,2);
  lambda  = 8;
  theta   = 0;
  psi     = [0 pi/2];
  gamma   = 0.5;
  bw      = 1;
  N       = 2;
  img_in = im2double(I);
  %img_in(:,:,2:3) = [];   % discard redundant channels, it's gray anyway
  img_out = zeros(size(img_in,1), size(img_in,2), N);
  for n=1:N
   gb = gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(1),lambda,theta)...
            + 1i * gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(2),lambda,theta);
 % gb is the n-th gabor filter
    img_out(:,:,n) = imfilter(img_in, gb, 'symmetric');
   % filter output to the n-th channel
   %theta = theta + 2*pi/N
  %figure;
  %imshow(img_out(:,:,n));
  imshow(img_in); hold on;
  h = imagesc(img_out(:,:,n)); % here i am getting error saying CDATA must be size[M*N]
  set( h, 'AlphaData', .5 ); % .5 transparency
  figure;
  imshow(h);
   theta = 15 * n;  % next orientation
  end
```

[image]
this is my original image

[image]
this is my visualized image got by gabor filter using orientation
[image]
this is the kind/type of image i have to get with respect to visualisation .i.e i have to impose visualized image on my original image and i have to get this type of image

Comment: Could you upload pictures of your results? Does you code even run, or does it spit out errors?

Comment: sir it gets executed...bt i am not getting the out what i want..I want my filterd output to be imposed on my original image and i want my 3rd image as output image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you have provided, my understanding is you want the third/final image to be an overlay on top of the first/initial image. I do things like this when using segmentation to detect hemorrhaging in MRI images of the brain.

First, let's set up some defintions:

- I_src = source/original image
- I_out = output/final image

Now, make a copy of `I_src` and make it a color image rather than grayscale.

```
I_hybrid = I_src
colorIm = gray2rgb(I_src)
```

Let's assume both `I_src` and `I_out` are the same visual dimensions (ie: width, height), and that `I_out` is **strictly** black-and-white (ie: monochrome). Now, we can use `I_out` as a mask template for alpha channel adjustments in the resulting image. This is where it gets fun.

```
BLACK=0;
WHITE=1;
[length width] = size(I_out);
for i = 1:1:length
   for j = 1:1:width
   if (I_out(i,j) == WHITE)
      I_hybrid(i,j) = I_hybrid(i,j) + [0.25 0 0]a;
   end
end
```

This will result in you getting your original image with the blood vessels in the eye being slightly brighter and tinted red. You now have a beautiful composite of your original image with the desired features highlighted, but not overwritten (ie: you can undo the highlighting by subtracting the original color vector).

I will include an example of what the output would look like, but it's noisy because I had to create it in GIMP as I don't have Matlab installed right now. The results will be similar, but yours would be much cleaner and prettier.

[image]

Please let me know how this goes.

---

**References**

1. "Converting Images from Grayscale to Color" http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/11/25/converting-images-from-grayscale-to-color/

Comment: thanks a lott for reply sir!!1 i am also doin my project on detection of abnormalities in retina. i will try with this and get back to you sir..anyways thanks a ton again sir!!

Comment: sir i am getting a error in the function .. the below line gives me error ???     Error using ==> plus Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

    Error in ==> file1>GABOR_Callback at 782
          I_hybrid(i,j) = I_hybrid(i,j) + [0.25 0 0];

Comment: Sir...i executed on ua code i changed this line to I_hybrid(i,j) = I_hybrid(i,j) + [0.25] , since it was giving an error .....when i run it it gave me a out put with 1 small dot...looks like i have missed out something donno what ? can u help me

Comment: @vidya With respect to your second comment above, we are trying to add two color vectors. Each pixel in your final image should be an RGB pixel, so each pixel can be represented as: `[ X Y [R G B] ]`. It might just be a dimensional issue.